# Ibm Watson Conversation Fuzzy Matching update causing issue with existing entities

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

The Fuzzy matching feature of Ibm watson conversation since its latest update is matching words incorrectly. Eg. "what" is getting picked up as entity "chatbot" whereas there is no synonym in chatbot entity that is even close to what.
My question is that is there a way to exclude words from fuzzy matching yet keeping it ON for the entity. Or any other solution to tackle this problem.

Thanks

Comment: I'm confuse. your entity @chatbot have one value with "what"? Can you please show one real example?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have an entity in chatbot for 'chat bot', and its getting a partial match on chat, and then doing fuzzy match from 'chat' to 'what' because its only one character difference and could be a spelling error. 
You can turn fuzzy matching off, but you cannot currently blacklist any specific words. You can also try to protect yourself by your dialog design in that youre only looking for @chatbot at certain points, so it shouldn't interrupt very often

Comment: Apologies for not explaining properly. You most part right. For now we have removed synonyms from chatbot entity to make it work fine. But there are multi string entities as well for which partial matching is behaving incorrectly. So 1) is there a way in which I can turn off partial matching from Fuzzy match. 2) Can we use entities.confidence> some value to make fuzzy mathcing work onlyif it is confident

Comment: please view updated answer above. But sorry no to both of your questions.

Answer (score 2):

I know what you mean, we need to use fuzzy matching, but it sometimes creates more trouble. We have had a number of words picked up and reported as something different. The method we use to remove some of the issues, is to view the confidence value that's given for the incorrect spelling "what" .. and then using this as an additional condition. 
i.e. if "what" reports a confidence value of 0.6 then set your condition to be 0.7 .. entities['chatbot']?.confidence > 0.7 
Fuzzy logic can be switched on or off for each individual "class" of entities, i.e. 'chatbot' in the example above or 'city' in many of the doc examples. 
I don't believe you can set a one global condition that checks all entities for there confidence value, so you do need to check the confidence at the class level. As shown above.
Also at present you cannot blacklist individual words to stop the fuzzy logic from checking them, like 'what' in your example.

Comment: Thanks for answer..really helpful. However I want to use the confidence property for the entire entity as a whole as there might be many such words like "what". That is something like entities.confidence>.7 . But this doesnt seem to work.. Any workaround for this mate?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can definitely examine the confidence value. One concern I have about that is that you have no idea how many entities you are receiving, so you will have to write some fairly complex logic, but if you only have one entity, its pretty simple. When we detect entities, we return this:

```
 "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "appliance",
      "location": [
        23,
        29
      ],
      "value": "wipers",
      "confidence": 1
    },
    {
      "entity": "appliance",
      "location": [
        11,
        18
      ],
      "value": "lights",
      "confidence": 0.87
    }
  ]
```

So to access the confidence of an entity you would do entity[0].confidence > 0.x in your dialog trigger.